# Microsoft office 365 Mail REST API in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, grails, office365

Hi I'm using a [Mail REST API for Office 365](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations)

I need to get a all messages more than 1 accounts. I tried to use '[getMessages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#MessageoperationsGetmessages)' API. But it prompts a login screen. I want to get logged in via program code so that a client should not login manually. Is there any java API or sdk I can use? Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is currently not available via the REST API. It is available via EWS. I know that the product team is aware of this feature request.

With regards,
Michael